# Python web crawler script cannot loop through pages of website. "&page=1" dissapears when entered manually in URL

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to create a web-crawler for gathering housing information. I've partially followed this guide throughout this project and made some adjustments along the way:
https://medium.com/@fneves/looking-for-a-house-build-a-web-scraper-to-help-you-5ab25badc83e

I can make the call by importing Selenium and I can get the information from the website with BeautifulSoup, that works fine. But when I've gathered the 20 housing results (that each page consists of) from page 1 I'm unable to switch page (url+ "&page=2" etc...), It does not let me switch to the next one. By entering my base-url manually in my browser, I get the first page. But when I try to add "&page=2" manually, it erases by itself and gives me the base-url and the first 20 results.

I believe my code is working, it is rather something with the website itself. Some sort of protection from webscraping maybe? Has anyone encountered the same problem before?

**This is the url when pressing the button for the second page:**
[image]

**This is the url when I've manually added the "&page=2", it resets to the normal one:**
[image]

Iv'e anonymized my code since I'm unsure of how ethical it is to webscrape data. This is my code:

```
title       = []
#location   = []
#MoveInDate     = []
#area       = []
#rooms      = []
#price      = []

# Loop through the pages

url = "https://www.xxx.se/search?"
n_pages = 0

for page in range(1,3):

    n_pages += 1
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chromedriver_path = 'path_to_chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(url+str(page))
    print("Link is: "+url+str(page))
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    house_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="A class")

    if len(house_containers) > 0:
        print('Values stored from website page #'+str(page))

    if house_containers != []:
        for initial in house_containers:

            # Title
            name = initial.find_all('p', class_="Another class")[0].text
            title.append(name)
    
    else:
        break
    
    time.sleep(2)

print('You scraped {} pages containing {} properties.'.format(n_pages, len(title)))

cols = ['Title']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': title})[cols]

df.to_csv('Path/Housing.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

I'm unsure of what I can try here, tried searching for a solution on google but none seems to have this particular problem.

Comment: **1st thing**: If button to next page exists, why are you simply not using that to move to next page in selenium using [driver.forward()](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/navigation/#forward)? **2nd**: that page *might* be checking its referrer. **Third**: you can keep that chrome_options, driver and imports outside the loop. **Fourth**: You can use [selenium finders/locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) and [selenium explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/)